# AppRTCDemo app crashes on iPhone5, iPad4 (iOS 8.1)

Tags: ios, webrtc, apprtcdemo

I just start researching webrtc. 
I can build the latest webrtc (r.8107). The AppRTCDemo is crashed when i join room.

It seem the resolution is so large. I try to change some code in ARDAppClient.m file:

```
// RTCMediaConstraints *mediaConstraints = [self defaultMediaStreamConstraints]; // I comment this line
RTCMediaConstraints *mediaConstraints = [self defaultOfferConstraints]; // Add this line
```

And run it again. It works but i cannot see iDevices's video stream on Firefox/Chrome https://apprtc.appspot.com

Please help me.
Thanks,

Comment: I am not sure that webrtc is supported on iOS devices in browser.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent I do not mention running webrtc on browser in iOS devices. I test AppRTCDemo app with Firefox/Chrome on pc.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread.

Comment: Please elaborate: Can you see/hear anything on any of the devices? If not, it's probably only the stuff on top webRTC is working (I suppose they use web socket messaging)

Comment: @InMyHumbleOpinion I can hear and see the video of pc side on my iPhone.

Comment: If you have NEITHER audio NOR video on your PC it's likely a general WebRTC issue with the app (or - less likely - a permission issue). If you have the audio stream, it's more likely a permission/configuration issue regarding video. I'm not into iOS, so I can't give further advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webrtc cummunity is aware of the crash issue http://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?can=2&q=4190&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&id=4190. It just happens to armv7 release.

Answer (score 0):

that caused by a stack over flow bug in vp8 decoding, that only crashed in armv7 devices. you can confirm this patch to fix that bug:

```
diff --git a/source/libvpx/vp8/common/arm/neon/vp8_subpixelvariance_neon.c b/source/libvpx/vp8/common/arm/neon/vp8_subpixelvariance_neon.c
index 8308d55..a66b6f5 100644
--- a/source/libvpx/vp8/common/arm/neon/vp8_subpixelvariance_neon.c
+++ b/source/libvpx/vp8/common/arm/neon/vp8_subpixelvariance_neon.c
@@ -1003,7 +1003,7 @@ unsigned int vp8_sub_pixel_variance8x8_neon(
         const unsigned char *dst,
         int dst_stride,
         unsigned int *sse) {
-  DECLARE_ALIGNED_ARRAY(kAlign16, uint8_t, temp2, kHeight8 * kWidth8);
+  DECLARE_ALIGNED_ARRAY(kAlign16, uint8_t, temp2, kHeight8PlusOne * kWidth8);
   DECLARE_ALIGNED_ARRAY(kAlign16, uint8_t, fdata3, kHeight8PlusOne * kWidth8);
   if (xoffset == 0) {
     var_filter_block2d_bil_w8(src, temp2, src_stride, kWidth8, kHeight8,
```

Wish this can help you!

The students of diveinedu.com have just overcome and fixed this bug.